# async import json file react js is still getting into the bundle

Tags: reactjs, web, importerror

I have a quick question, I am working on a reactjs app, so I have a json static file with some countries information to be shown on a  HTML component, my real issue is how to import it without getting its weight into my bundle, this is the way I am importing now and it is not even working

```
    import('assets/jsons/countries.json').then((countries) => {
      setCountries(Object.values(countries).reduce((acc, val) => ({ ...acc, [val.code2]: val }), {}));
    });
```

Comment: Please keep in mind im importing it into the useEffect hook

Comment: If you don't want it bundled, you have to ajax it in.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want it bundled in, then you can create a custom hook that loads it in and have your json file on a static server to serve it.

```
export default function useCountriesList(jsonUrl){
    const [list, setList] = useState({});
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        // load ajax file
        fetch(jsonUrl)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(json => setList(Object.values(json.countries)))
            .finally(() => setLoading(false));
    }, [])
 
    return [list, loading]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's assume you have a `data.json` file wright beside your component file:

```
 const getData=()=>{
    fetch('data.json'
    ,{
      headers: { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
       }
    }
    )
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => data);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    getData()
  },[])
```